# How can i apply my custom catalog price rule condition in Magento 1?

Tags: php, magento, module

I need a catalog price rule that applies to products with a SKU that **starts** with two letters. So something like this: `LIKE AB%'. This is currently not possible (there is a %value% option, but that's not what i need).

I'm able to show my new operator in the catalog rule creation tab. Unfortunatly i'm unable to find the specific part or parts to overwrite that actually applies this new condition. Been tracing and trying allot for several hours, but can't find it. So what's next, what should i override to apply my new operator?

Peer1979/Modulename/etc/local.xml

```xml
<config>    
    <global> 
    <models>
            <catalogrule>
                <rewrite>
                    <rule_condition_combine>Peer1979_Modulename_Model_CatalogRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Combine</rule_condition_combine>    
                    <rule_condition_product>Peer1979_Modulename_Model_CatalogRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product</rule_condition_product>
                </rewrite>                
            </catalogrule>
        </models> 
        </global>
</config>
```

Peer1979/Modulename/Model/CatalogRule/Model/Rule/Condition/TraitDefaultOperator.php

```php
<?php

trait TraitDefaultOperator
{
    /*
     * @var string  Operator starts with (f.e. LIKE ST%)
     */

    private $operator_starts_with = '^[]';

    /*
     * Get default operator input by type, extended with new operator '^[]'.
     */

    private function getDefaultAndCustomOperatorInputByType()
    {
        return [
            'string' => array('==', '!=', '>=', '>', '<=', '<', '{}', '!{}', '()', '!()', $this->operator_starts_with),
            'numeric' => array('==', '!=', '>=', '>', '<=', '<', '()', '!()'),
            'date' => array('==', '>=', '<='),
            'datetime' => array('==', '>=', '<='),
            'select' => array('==', '!='),
            'boolean' => array('==', '!='),
            'multiselect' => array('[]', '![]', '()', '!()'),
            'grid' => array('()', '!()'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Default operator options getter
     * Provides all possible operator options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDefaultOperatorOptions()
    {
        if (null === $this->_defaultOperatorOptions) {
            $this->_defaultOperatorOptions = $this->getDefaultAndCustomOperatorOptions();
        }
        return $this->_defaultOperatorOptions;
    }
    /*
     * Get default operator  options, extended with new operator '^[]'.
     */

    private function >getDefaultAndCustomOperatorOptions()
    {
        return [
            //default magento operators
            '==' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('is'),
            '!=' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('is not'),
            '>=' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('equals or greater than'),
            '<=' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('equals or less than'),
            '>' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('greater than'),
            '<' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('less than'),
            '{}' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('contains'),
            '!{}' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('does not contain'),
            '[]' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('contains'),
            '![]' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('does not contain'),
            '()' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('is one of'),
            '!()' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('is not one of'),

            //custom magento operators
            $this->operator_starts_with => Mage::helper('rule')->__('[custom] starts with'),
        ];
    }
```

Peer1979/Modulename/Model/CatalogRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Combine.php

```php
<?php

require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/TraitDefaultOperator.php');

class Peer1979_Modulename_Model_CatalogRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Combine extends Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Combine
{
    use TraitDefaultOperator;

    /**
     * Default operator input by type map getter
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDefaultOperatorInputByType()
    {
        if (null === $this->_defaultOperatorInputByType) {
            $this->_defaultOperatorInputByType = $this->getDefaultAndCustomOperatorInputByType();
            $this->_arrayInputTypes = array('multiselect', 'grid');
        }
        return $this->_defaultOperatorInputByType;
    }
}
```

Peer1979/Modulename/Model/CatalogRule/Rule/Condition/

```php
<?php

require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/TraitDefaultOperator.php');

class Peer1979_Modulename_Model_CatalogRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product extends Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product
{
    use TraitDefaultOperator;

    /**
     * Default operator input by type map getter
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDefaultOperatorInputByType()
    {
        if (null === $this->_defaultOperatorInputByType) {
            $this->_defaultOperatorInputByType = $this->getDefaultAndCustomOperatorInputByType();
            $this->_arrayInputTypes = array('multiselect', 'grid');

            //additional mangento default overrides
            $this->_defaultOperatorInputByType['category'] = array('==', '!=', '{}', '!{}', '()', '!()');
            $this->_arrayInputTypes[] = 'category';
        }
        return $this->_defaultOperatorInputByType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! With this code you can create a custom price rule condition. Note that this only works for string values. For future reference or anyone interested:

Peer1979/Modulename/etc/local.xml

```xml
<config>    
    <global> 
    <models>
            <catalogrule>
                <rewrite>
                    <rule_condition_combine>Peer1979_Modulename_Model_CatalogRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Combine</rule_condition_combine>    
                    <rule_condition_product>Peer1979_Modulename_Model_CatalogRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product</rule_condition_product>
                </rewrite>                
            </catalogrule>
        </models> 
        </global>
</config>
```

Peer1979/Modulename/Model/CatalogRule/Model/Rule/Condition/TraitDefaultOperator.php

```php
<?php

trait TraitDefaultOperator
{
    /*
     * @var string  Operator starts with (f.e. LIKE ST%)
     */

    private $operator_starts_with = '^[]';

    /*
     * Get default operator input by type, extended with new operator '^[]'.
     */

    private function getDefaultAndCustomOperatorInputByType()
    {
        return [
            'string' => array('==', '!=', '>=', '>', '<=', '<', '{}', '!{}', '()', '!()', $this->operator_starts_with),
            'numeric' => array('==', '!=', '>=', '>', '<=', '<', '()', '!()'),
            'date' => array('==', '>=', '<='),
            'datetime' => array('==', '>=', '<='),
            'select' => array('==', '!='),
            'boolean' => array('==', '!='),
            'multiselect' => array('[]', '![]', '()', '!()'),
            'grid' => array('()', '!()'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Default operator options getter
     * Provides all possible operator options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDefaultOperatorOptions()
    {
        if (null === $this->_defaultOperatorOptions) {
            $this->_defaultOperatorOptions = $this->getDefaultAndCustomOperatorOptions();
        }
        return $this->_defaultOperatorOptions;
    }
    /*
     * Get default operator  options, extended with new operator '^[]'.
     */

    private function >getDefaultAndCustomOperatorOptions()
    {
        return [
            //default magento operators
            '==' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('is'),
            '!=' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('is not'),
            '>=' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('equals or greater than'),
            '<=' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('equals or less than'),
            '>' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('greater than'),
            '<' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('less than'),
            '{}' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('contains'),
            '!{}' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('does not contain'),
            '[]' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('contains'),
            '![]' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('does not contain'),
            '()' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('is one of'),
            '!()' => Mage::helper('rule')->__('is not one of'),

            //custom magento operators
            $this->operator_starts_with => Mage::helper('rule')->__('[custom] starts with'),
        ];
    }
```

Peer1979/Modulename/Model/CatalogRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Combine.php

```php
<?php

require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/TraitDefaultOperator.php');

class Peer1979_Modulename_Model_CatalogRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Combine extends Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Combine
{
    use TraitDefaultOperator;

    /**
     * Default operator input by type map getter
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDefaultOperatorInputByType()
    {
        if (null === $this->_defaultOperatorInputByType) {
            $this->_defaultOperatorInputByType = $this->getDefaultAndCustomOperatorInputByType();
            $this->_arrayInputTypes = array('multiselect', 'grid');
        }
        return $this->_defaultOperatorInputByType;
    }
}
```

Peer1979/Modulename/Model/CatalogRule/Rule/Condition/

```php
<?php

require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/TraitDefaultOperator.php');

class Peer1979_Modulename_Model_CatalogRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product extends Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product
{
    use TraitDefaultOperator;

    /**
     * Default operator input by type map getter
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDefaultOperatorInputByType()
    {
        if (null === $this->_defaultOperatorInputByType) {
            $this->_defaultOperatorInputByType = $this->getDefaultAndCustomOperatorInputByType();
            $this->_arrayInputTypes = array('multiselect', 'grid');

            //additional mangento default overrides
            $this->_defaultOperatorInputByType['category'] = array('==', '!=', '{}', '!{}', '()', '!()');
            $this->_arrayInputTypes[] = 'category';
        }
        return $this->_defaultOperatorInputByType;
    }

  /**
     * Validate product attribute value for condition
     * Note: code is much like Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Abstract > validate_attribute, with adjustments for new operator(s).
     *
     * @param   mixed $validatedValue product attribute value
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function validateAttribute($validatedValue)
    {
        /* Code equal to original code */

        if (is_object($validatedValue)) {
            return false;
        }

        $value = $this->getValueParsed();       //Condition value
        $op = $this->getOperatorForValidate();  //Condition operator

        // if operator requires array and it is not, or on opposite, return false
        if ($this->isArrayOperatorType() xor is_array($value)) {
            return false;
        }

        $result = false;

        /* END Code equal to original code */

        switch ($op) {
            case $this->operator_starts_with:   //ok
                $value = (array)$value;
                foreach ($value as $item) {
                    //only support for strings!
                    //validate when one item starts with
                    if (strpos($validatedValue, $item) === 0)
                    {
                        $result = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                break;
            default:    //ok
                $result = Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Abstract::validateAttribute($validatedValue);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```